# How can I count unanswered messages in the last year?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a messaging system. Messages are two different kinds.

- The first messages have a `title` and `NULL` for `related` column.
- The second messages are related to one of the first messages which don't have `title` and they have the id of parent message for `related` column. (which are known as response/reply/answer)

Here is my table structure:

```
// messages
+----+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| id |  title   |     content      | sender_id | receiver_id |  date_time  | related |
+----+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| 1  | titel1   | whatever1        | 1         | 3           | 1521097240  | NULL    |
| 2  |          | whatever2        | 3         | 1           | 1521097241  | 1       |
| 3  |          | whatever3        | 1         | 3           | 1521097242  | 1       |
| 4  | title2   | whatever4        | 1         | 4           | 1521097243  | NULL    |
| 5  | title3   | whatever5        | 1         | 5           | 1521097244  | NULL    |
| 6  |          | whatever7        | 4         | 1           | 1521097246  | 4       |
| 7  | title4   | whatever8        | 1         | 4           | 1521097246  | NULL    |
+----+----------+------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------+
/*
  related column: it is NULL for the first message and the id of the parent for othesrs.
```

Now I need to count the number of messages that user A sent and hasn't receive a response for that in the last year.

For example, the number of messages user `user_id = 1` has sent which hasn't gotten a response for is `1`. Because he has sent a message to user `user_id = 5` and he hasn't responded yet.

How can I count that number?

---

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM messages
WHERE sender_id = 1
  AND date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

My query counts all sent messages. How can I count only the unanswered ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that you really mean *first* messages sent by "A".  If so, your sample query needs to filter on `related is NULL`.  To filter on the non-responses, you can use `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE` or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM messages m LEFT JOIN
     messages m2
     ON m2.related = m.id
WHERE m.sender_id = 1 AND
      m.related IS NULL AND
      m.date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND
      m2.id IS NULL;  -- response does not exist
```

Comment: Also you're missed `AND` after `m.related IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM messages m1
WHERE sender_id = 1  AND 
      related IS NULL AND
      date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM messages m2
          WHERE m1.id = m2.related
      )
```

Comment: Yeah it works well. thank you. upvote https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=bda7b015350532d210094bbb9b4c5911